# Issues in Apache CXF for getting server stacktrace in Exception_Exception

Tags: java, web-services, apache, exception, cxf

I have implemented Apache CXF WebService and trying to access WebService through Swings Application.
The problem that I am facing is CXF has created a class named Exception_Exception in client side from the WSDL. When an exception occurs in server side, the client Exception_Exception gets invokes but I don't receive the same stack trace of server in Exception_Exception stack trace.
Below is the class generated by CXF:

```
package com.abc.it.vcare.service;

import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-752-
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebFault(name = "Exception", targetNamespace = "http://service.vcare.it.abc.com/")
public class Exception_Exception
    extends java.lang.Exception
{

/**
 * Java type that goes as soapenv:Fault detail element.
 * 
 */
private com.axiom.it.vcare.service.Exception faultInfo;

/**
 * 
 * @param message
 * @param faultInfo
 */
public Exception_Exception(String message, com.axiom.it.vcare.service.Exception faultInfo) {
    super(message);
    this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param message
 * @param faultInfo
 * @param cause
 */
public Exception_Exception(String message, com.axiom.it.vcare.service.Exception faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns fault bean: com.axiom.it.vcare.service.Exception
 */
public com.axiom.it.vcare.service.Exception getFaultInfo() {
    return faultInfo;
}

}
```

Please help, what should I do to get the same StackTrace given in Server Exception in my client side Exception_Exception.

Thanks,
Jai G.

Answer (score 1):

What version of CXF are you using? This is an old CXF issue that has been addressed in the most recent versions. Try using version 2.7.0 of CXF, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Currently there is cxf-2.4.2.jar in my lib, you want me to update it by putting 2.7.0 JAR, correct me if I am wrong? Also I read in migration guide in Apache site, and it didnt mention to resolve this issue. Is it something that I am missing out here?